# Replace header text with button text using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, onclick

I am using only JavaScript to create buttons and need to add click handlers to the buttons that will replace the header with the contents of the buttons. I have been trying to figure out how to do this for a while. Any help would be great! Thank you!

Below is my JavaScript code that creates the buttons and header.

```
var col = document.createElement('div');
col.className = 'col';
document.body.appendChild(col);

var header = document.getElementById('col');
var h = document.createElement("H3");
h.innerHTML = "Nothing clicked yet!";
col.appendChild(h);

var divOne = document.createElement('div');
col.appendChild(divOne);

var btnOne = document.getElementById('col');
var textOne = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
textOne.forEach(function(post) {
    var postDiv = document.createElement("div");
    postDiv.className = 'btn btn-default';
    postDiv.innerHTML = post;
    col.appendChild(postDiv);
});
```

Comment: With this much code you might get a better response if you posted a working example and comment key lines that correspond to you question. Another helpful strategy is to boil down your code into just enough to display the problem. For instance, if you leave the header and one button, you could then apply the concept to the rest of your code. Jsfiddle, codepen, plunker are all online tools that allow you to do this.

Comment: Is this what you are trying to accomplish? https://jsfiddle.net/25mpjvcq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an event to your button elements, but as other answers pointed out, a good practice is to assign IDs to your elements for more accurate lookup :

```
var btnOne = document.getElementById('col');
    var textOne = ["Left", "Middle", "Right"];
    textOne.forEach(function(post) {
        var btnGroupFour = document.createElement('button');
        btnGroupFour.className = 'btn btn-default';
        btnGroupFour.innerHTML = post;
        btnGroupFour.addEventListener("click", function() {
        var header = document.getElementsByTagName('H3')[0];
        header.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
    }, false);
        divThree.appendChild(btnGroupFour);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are not creating `button`s, you're creating `div`s, although you're using the button classes from bootstrap (I gues...).

Anyway, the way to proceed would be to add a `onclick` attribute with a callback function, witch takes one argument: the event itself. Then, with the `target` attribute of the event object, you're getting access to the event source tag and with `value` you will get the value.

Just like this:

```
<input type="button" id="button" value="Test Value!" />
<span id="output"></span>
<script>
    document.getElementById("button").addEventListener('click', callback);
    function callback(e) { document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = e.target.value; }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Just assign an ID for your header, and while creating the buttons in the loop. Just assign the onclick callback of the button, to get the id of the header, and replace the text

textOne.forEach(function(post) {
        var btnGroupFour = document.createElement('button');
        btnGroupFour.className = 'btn btn-default';
        btnGroupFour.innerHTML = post;
        btnGroupFour.onclick =  function(){document.getElementById('headerID').innerHTML = post} ;
        h.appendChild(btnGroupFour);
    });
```

Should Work for your situation.

A short [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/v0e7yr4b/)

Answer (score 0):

Fairly simple, just add an eventListener onto the element during creation. All I really had to add to your code was: .addEventListener("click", function(){ h.innerHTML = post;});

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Hover over the checkbox to simulate a mouse-click.</p>

<script>
var divContainer = document.createElement('div');
divContainer.className = 'container';
document.body.appendChild(divContainer);

var row = document.createElement('div');
row.className = 'row';
divContainer.appendChild(row);

var col = document.createElement('div');
col.id = 'col-md-12';
row.appendChild(col);

var header = document.getElementById('col');
var h = document.createElement("H3");
h.innerHTML = "Nothing clicked yet!";
col.appendChild(h);

var star = document.createElement('div');
col.appendChild(star);

var btnStar = document.getElementById('col');
var textStar = ["Star"];
textStar.forEach(function(post) {
    var postStar = document.createElement("div");
    postStar.className = 'btn btn-default';
    postStar.innerHTML = post;
    postStar.addEventListener("click", function(){
    h.innerHTML = post;});
    col.appendChild(postStar);

});


var secondLine = document.createElement("HR");
document.body.appendChild(secondLine);
col.appendChild(secondLine);

var divOne = document.createElement('div');
col.appendChild(divOne);

var btnOne = document.getElementById('col');
var textOne = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
textOne.forEach(function(post) {
    var postDiv = document.createElement("div");
    postDiv.className = 'btn btn-default';
    postDiv.innerHTML = post;
    postDiv.addEventListener("click", function(){
    h.innerHTML = post;});
    col.appendChild(postDiv);

});


var btnTwo = document.getElementById('col');
var textTwo = ["5", "6", "7", "8"];
textTwo.forEach(function(post) {
    var btnGroupFour = document.createElement('button');
    btnGroupFour.className = 'btn btn-default';
    btnGroupFour.innerHTML = post;
    btnGroupFour.addEventListener("click", function(){
    h.innerHTML = post;});
    col.appendChild(btnGroupFour);
});


var secondLine = document.createElement("HR");
document.body.appendChild(secondLine);
col.appendChild(secondLine);

var divThree = document.createElement('div');
col.appendChild(divThree);

var btnOne = document.getElementById('col');
var textOne = ["Left", "Middle", "Right"];
textOne.forEach(function(post) {
    var btnGroupFour = document.createElement('button');
    btnGroupFour.className = 'btn btn-default';
    btnGroupFour.innerHTML = post;
    btnGroupFour.addEventListener("click", function(){
    h.innerHTML = post;});
    divThree.appendChild(btnGroupFour);
});


</script>


</body>
</html>
```